# Render text in the shape of an image with Python

Tags: python, text-rendering

I want to render text so that it looks like a given image, for example:

[image: raven]

The same thing as this, but in Python: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183447/how-compose-an-image-from-a-specific-text

I looked through the Pillow documentation but don't find anything relevant. Am I anything obvious? will I need to implement it myself from scratch?

Comment: There won't be anything off the shelf to help you with this task, it's not something that anybody tries to do on a regular basis. The hardest part will be to resize the image so that the text just fits.

Comment: this is called ASCII-art, you can easily google dozen of solutions. If you want to implement it yourself, not to create few-lines wrapper - then it's up to you to chose approach

Comment: FYI, I've found the ready solution in 1 minute, implemented using Pillow in less then 60 lines of code, on the first page of Google SERP. You can follow the [link](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/beautiful-python-a-simple-ascii-art-generator-from-images/)

Comment: @agg3l really? do you mean random ASCII-art algo, ie filling the image with random text, or with a specific text that fits the image shape? Link?

Comment: The one I've mentioned before uses _grayscale_-like image, filling it with chars. Actually, to fill it with text you just should convert image to bitmap (i.e. black & white pixels) then fill in the bits. I'm surprised myself how simple it is, although never bothered before how to implement one

Comment: @agg3l most ASCII art, including the link you found, is a completely different problem to the one posted in the question.